# Converte json file to csv file with proper formatted rows and columns in excel

Tags: python, pandas, linux, csv

Currently I'm working a script that can convert json file to csv format my script is working but I need to modify it to have proper data format like having rows and columns when the json file is converted to csv file, May I know what I need to add or modify on my script?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json (r'/home/admin/myfile.json')
df.to_csv (r'/home/admin/xml/myfileSample.csv', index = None, sep=":")
```

Comment: If you want Excel, why are you using `to_csv` instead of `to_excel`? CSV files aren't Excel files. As the name says, they're text files with Comma Separated Values. Just text with commas

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from your code,you can try

```
df.to_csv(r'/home/admin/xml/myfileSample.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=header,index = None, sep=":")
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful.

```
import pandas as pd

df_json=pd.read_json("input_file.json")
df_json.head()
df_json.to_csv("output_file.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all fine, Just change the to_csv to to_excel function and it should work all fine!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json (r'/home/admin/myfile.json')
df.to_excel (r'/home/admin/xml/myfileSample.csv', index = None, sep=":")
```

Learn more about the to_excel function of pandas here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: For your new prob can you please provide that JSON file?